# How to Delete a Specific Child Node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling

I have the following Code

```js
  <script>        
      function delete(){
          var e = document.getElementById('parent');
          e.removeChild(e.children[0]);
      }
</script>
```

```html
  <div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
          <input type="text" placeholder="name"> 
          <button onclick="delete()"> delete</button>
      </div>
    
      <div id="child">
          <input type="text" placeholder="age"> 
          <button onclick="delete()"> delete</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

When I press the delete button, the first child node gets deleted. However, I want to delete only the specific child node. For example: if I click the delete button in the name input field only the name input field should be deleted.

Comment: you tagged your question with 'jquery', but you are not using jquery.  Do you want to use jquery? or would you rather use plain javascript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
function delete(){
    $(this).parent().remove()
}
```

and you can't use same `id` for different `div`

Comment: you can try this by javascript  ```this.parentElement.remove()```

Comment: this will not work, `delete` is reserved keyword and even if the function name is changed,  `this` will reference the global object not the button.

Answer (score 6):

this is fully working example.

```js
function deleteNode(item){
    item.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```html
 <div id="parent">
     <div id="child">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"> 
      <button onclick="deleteNode(this)"> delete</button>
     </div>

     <div id="child">
      <input type="text" placeholder="age"> 
      <button onclick="deleteNode(this)"> delete</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two lines:

```
var e = document.getElementById('parent');    
e.removeChild(e.children[0]);
```

here you are getting an element by its id, and the id is 'parent'.
This will always give you the div.

Then you delete the first child of e.

You need a different method of getting the element to delete!

A first step would be to look at the target of your
event handler:

```
   function delete(ev){
     var target = ev.target;
     console.log("the element that was clicked is ", target);
     // continue from here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost,  `delete` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) you cannot use it for a function name.

Secondly, you must pass a reference of the element being clicked. This can be achieved by passing the `this` argument to your onclick handler:

```
<button onclick="deleteParent(this)"> delete</button>
```

This will result in the following

```
 <div id="parent">
     <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"> 
      <button onclick="deleteParent(this)"> delete</button>
     </div>

     <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="age"> 
      <button onclick="deleteParent(this)"> delete</button>
     </div>
 </div>

 <script>
   function deleteParent(btn){
     btn.parentNode.remove();
   }
 </script>
```

You should also not use the same `id` on multiple elements.